# Problems with Heroku Rails 4 Amazon Cloudfront CDN and SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Rails 4 on Heroku, force_ssl = true, with the asset_host configured to a Cloudfront CDN, which is configured to use the Heroku rails server as the origin, and to have 'match protocol' set to true. I have a similar setup on a staging instance that uses a self-signed certificate. Because of the self signing, on the staging instance, force_ssl is false, and the CDN is configured to force HTTP (rather than HTTPS).

The problem is that the production server deployment is failing to refresh the CDN's version of the minified application.js. The SHA changes with each deployment, **AND** I've verified:

- The version from the CDN is **NOT** the same version as the one substituting the host URL to the Heroku server. The CDN is serving an older version of the JS.

Thus:

1. Deployment runs smoothly, pushing changes.
2. rake assets:precompile runs during deployment, creating a newly named application-new-sha.js file.
3. this new js file is referenced in the HTML pages served after deployment, with the CDN URL.
4. The version of the JS from the CDN is from an older deployment.
5. The version of the JS substituting the rails server host gets the right JS.
6. The staging server does not have this issue, and the only difference is that the origin of the assets is HTTP rather than HTTPS.

This is absolutely maddening.

I'm considering going back to using S3 and the asset_sync gem to hopefully avoid this issue.

Any advice on troubleshooting this? or working around the issue?

Comment: Hi Justin, did you find a solution to this? I understand it's 2 and a half years later and you might not remember. Thanks.